# Postgresql,multiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2, postgresql-9.4

I'm using postgresql 9.4.8 . In pg_log, i found a statement like,

> LOG:  MultiXact member wraparound protections are now enabled.

I can't find what this means. I didn't see these kind of statements in  postgresql 9.2.1.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/release-9-3-7.html

> Protect against wraparound of multixact member IDs (Álvaro Herrera,
>   Robert Haas, Thomas Munro)

It's new feature of 9.3

also read https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/routine-vacuuming.html#VACUUM-FOR-MULTIXACT-WRAPAROUND

Comment: Thanks. In my pgsql 9.2.1 pg_logs, i got an error like, **ERROR: database is not accepting commands to avoid wraparound data loss in database XXX** . is pgsql 9.2.1 cannot prevent wraparound data loss ? or is there any special cases, it may fail to auto-vacuum ? In general, why i need this new feature ?